# Unable to curl POST textfile to python flask server on localhost

Tags: php, python, file, curl, post

I have a functioning flask server on localhost and it's serving GET and POST requests normally when tested to serve simple python dictionaries. 
Now I'm trying to upload and read contents of a text file using the PHP script below (both file and script are in the same Windows directory):

```
<?  
    /*testscript.php*/  

    $url='http://localhost/transaction'
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $cfile = new CURLFile('sampledata.txt','text/plain','data_file');
    $data = array('test_file' => $cfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);   
    curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

And my flask server code in `views.py`:

```
@app.route('/transaction', methods=['POST'])
def read_file():
    if request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/plain':
        return "Text Message: " + request.data
```

I then start the flask server, which shows (run.py is the `FLASK_APP` variable):

```
* Serving Flask app "run"
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Next, when I enter `/localhost/testscript.php` in my browser, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You mean: http://localhost/testscript.php right? Do you have an .htaccess file?

Comment: @GustavoJantsch yes localhost/testscript.php. I'm not sure if I have a .htaccess. Is that required for this?

Comment: You can check with a `ls -al ` on your document root directory. Also, have you tried to list the content on `http://localhost/` ?

Comment: Checked it, there's no .htaccess in either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your python service on port 5000 you need to change the URL to be used on CURL to:

```
$url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/transaction'
```